# Create new list item with REST API and get item ID in function callback

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, sharepoint-list

Sometimes I need to create a new item with an attachment to a list in Sharepoint by using REST API.

What I used to do to achieve this task was to first create the item in the Sharepoint list by using the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('${listName}')/items`,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value,
    }
}).then( (data) => {
      const id = data.d.Id;
      // function to upload attachment here
});
```

This works just fine. However, I am trying to drop using jquery and move to ES6 features like fetch.
With fetch I am able to create a Sharepoint List Item with the code below, but I don't get the posted data in the callback, and therefore I am missing the newly created item Id that I need in order to upload the attachment

```
const url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('${resourceList}')/items`;

const options = {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item)
};

fetch(url, options)
    .then( (data) => {
        const id = data.d.Id;
        // not working, how can I get the newly created item Id in this callback?
    });
```

Does anyone know how can i achieve the same result I used to get with jQuery ajax, by using javascript fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it something as below:

```
fetch(url, options)
    .then((data) => {
        
    if(data.ok){
        data.json().then(value => {
            const id = value.d.Id;      
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working, thank you! Just a question: I tested your solution also in the case I am updating (MERGE) an existing list item. In such case it is not working, and I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".
I understand that if I am updating an item I already know the Id, so it is not really needed, but I am still curious why such an error appears. Do you know why?

Comment: You need to check the `data` object in that scenario. In some case, it doesn't give the JSON response, sometimes it just gives a response code etc. You can check in the `console.log`

Comment: That is what i tried to do. The data I get back tells me the status of the calls, but when I apply to it in a merge call the .json() method the code breaks

Comment: ok, so in that case, you can check the Chrome/Edge network tab see what the actual raw response is and change the code accordingly. Sometimes, you don't get the response obj back, just a status code that the request was success etc, so a check like if data.ok then check if data contains obj etc.

Comment: So, after further inspection, the response object I get when I create the element has a status 201 (Created), while the one I get after updating an element has a status 204 (No content). This is the only difference. Do you know how can I get in both cases a status 201?

Comment: No you don't get 201 in both cases. It is by design.